# Soundcloud API PHP Integration

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I am currently trying to stream tracks from soundcloud to my new web app. I currently am able to get the album cover but now I am need to get the user name, track title, and permalink to also show up under the album cover. This is my code so far

```
<body onload="setupBlocks();">

<?php 
    if(isset($tracks)){
        foreach($tracks as $track){
            debug($track['stream_url']);
            debug($track['artist']);

            echo '<div class="block">';
            echo "<p><img src='".$track['artwork_url']."' width='275' height='125' /></p>";
```

Do I need to just do another echo statement `echo "<p><src='".$track['title']."'/></p>";`?

...and to follow the same echo statement format for the username, and permalink as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. If you have a track resource already, you have access to all the information you need. Just issue some more echo statements like the following:

```
echo $track['title'];
echo $track['user']['username'];
echo $track['permalink_url'];
```

If you'd like to see all of the fields available, you could try the following debug statement:

```
print_r($track);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am pretty new to backend development and PHP. What is the exact syntax that I would need to use in order to call the echo statement in a specific div container. I currently have it as echo "<p><src='".$track['title']."'/></p>";